# Eclipse without project

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Simple question: I'd like to just hack around with `Eclipse` and `PyDev`. Is there any way I can just make a new blank python file on my disk and start editing it without going through the whole project setup stuff?

Comment: What happens when you open one from the File menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create at-least one project there is no escape from it.

Better suggestion:

Create at least one project in pydev.
Then copy the python code to clipboard by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Select any project in `Project Explorer` or `Pydev Package Explorer` view and paste the code by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then pydev asks for the file name by default it will be **snippet.py**

You can run this python file also inside pydev provided you configured PYTHONPATH in `Window-Preferences` already.

### Edit

You can also link your python files inside eclipse without copying into project.

How:

Drag the python file(s) and drop these file(s) on any project in `Project Explorer` or `Pydev Package Explorer`. 
Then eclipse ask for you to copy files/link to files as shown below:

[image]

And you can run these files inside pydev. Similarly you can drag and drop folder inside project and link them.

[image]

Be Careful: If you delete these linked files/folders then these files/folder will be deleted from the original location.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind, but I doesn't seem much better than just having the file in the project to begin with...

Comment: No it is not possible in eclipse world as eclipse has the concept called workspace. This workspace is managed by eclipse. In workspace project is considered as the top most container. Files and folders must be created inside project. Also you can't create project inside project. I think it is not only with eclipse even other IDE's also has at-least some initial set-up.

Comment: Just to note, you can drop an external file in Eclipse and run it with 'F9', but it still requires a project (mostly because that's from where it resolves the PYTHONPATH it uses -- so, in the minimum, you do have to create a PyDev project, even if it has no files inside it).